# Can I rsync a tar file as it's still being created?

Tags: linux, rsync, tar

I have a daily process that creates a snapshot of a very large mysql database (>500gb) into a backup.tar.gz file.  I'd like to rsync this file to another remote machine.  Transferring the data will take much longer than the actual creation of the backup, so I'm wondering...

Can I start a transfer of the backup.tar.gz file using rsync before it's fully completed so by the time it's done, most of the data has already been moved to the other remote machine?  Or would this corrupt the tar.gz file and not work?

Comment: I would consider doing things otherwise. You certainly can use `mysqldump` do make some partial dumps. Then you'll have several files, and `rsync`-ing them should be easier.

Comment: mysqldump would be much too slow for the size of this database.  We use xtrabackup.  This question is really more for a one-time thing than a daily process I want to setup for the long-term.  Trying to save a couple hours today so I can start restoring the backup on a 2nd remote server earlier.

Comment: If you're doing rsync over SSH then it may be simpler just to skip the rsync and use SSH directly - `tar czf - | ssh destinationserver /bin/sh -c 'cat > /path/to/file.tar.gz'` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah I think that will work. Because `gzip` is a filtering compression, which means it can compress and decompress a stream of data, in a sort of incremental way. This implies that the compressed data that's already written will not change later, so you can copy with `rsync` a partial file and continue copying the rest later.

If in doubt, do a proof of concept sanity test and compare checksums.

**UPDATE**

When transferring large files, it's good to enable the `--partial` flag, so that in case the transfer gets interrupted, `rsync` will keep the partially transferred file so you can continue later. Another related useful flag is `--progress`. In fact it's easier to just use the shorter `-P` flag, which is the same as using both `--partial` and `--progress`.

Comment: Thanks! Running the proof of concept now.. will update when its all said and done.

Comment: I'm an idiot- forgot to add --partial to the original rsync I started while the backup was running.. will have to try again next time backup is running

Comment: @alex yeah, probably I should have mentioned that. Updated my post now.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync compares source and destination in several ways some of which are date of modification, size and checksum. If the size or checksum changes, rsync will complain that the file has changed.You might as well wait until tar completes.